# Delphi: click web page buttons by code to initiate download

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium-embedded, save-as

I am new to web development so please be patient.

I need to automate downloading a CSV file from an online location service every half hour. I am using Delphi 11.2 and [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi). I can navigate to the page, but cannot figure out how to click the button and wait for the response before clicking the next.

I have tried:

```pascal
WVBrowser.ExecuteScript('document.getElementById("linkRefresh")[0].click()');
```

...and different variations.

I need to click two buttons:

```html
<a id="linkRefresh"
   href="#"
   class="tools refresh report-action"
   data-action="refreshReport"
   data-event="click">
```

...and:

```html
<a id="linkCSV"
   href="#"
   class="csv report-action tools"
   data-action="exportCsv"
   data-event="click">
```

Then the "Save As" button, give a filename, and finally "Yes" to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: [`document.getElementById('id')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an `Element`, not a `HTMLCollection` (because identifiers are unique). Remove `[0]`. The "_"SaveAs" button_" is not part of the website, see [How to download and save as](https://www.briskbard.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1736) - it should be similar for WebView4Delphi.

Comment: I started without [0], that's just one of the many efforts. Been at it all morning. WebView4Delphi has many examples, but all just deal with the browser itself not content. I know it will be embarrassingly easy once I am pointed the right direction

Comment: Why not simply determine the final URL of the file and then download it directly, such as with `TIdHTTP`, `THTTPRequest`, `TRESTRequest`, etc? Is the 1st button click doing something that affects how the file is accessed by the second button click?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is not necessary that the said file even has a URL. It is possible that it is being downloaded as a Data Stream.

Comment: I believe it is as the first button updates the report. I just tried it a few minutes apart and got /report/ReportExporting.aspx?reportid=70009601&outputtype=csv first time then 70009654 next time. I however am still at the first hurdle, from everything I have looked at this should work WVBrowser.ExecuteScript('document.getElementById("linkRefresh").click()'); but nothing happens

Comment: I tried code out on different web sites, and all works fine including download, so I must not be getting the correct element?? The above elements are in different lists buried several levels into HTML. Do I need more than just the ID??